# How to generate SSL certificate on subdomain?

Tags: ssl, java, subdomain, glassfish, soap

I actually have a hosting service who has a subdomain, that subdomain function is to redirect to my local server where I have my services, for example:

My domain: example.com

Subdomain: guaymas.example.com // His function is to redirect to my server (firewall)

Redirect to a port : guaymas.example.com:8080 // where I have my services

And through a port I have a web service, in order to make the data transfer more secure I wanted to implement a SSL certificate but because of my configuration I’ḿ not able to generate the certificate with letś encrypt (because buying one is not an option), I can’t verify with http or dns method, Is there any other method that I can use to generate the SSL certificate?

PD: I'm using GlassFish and Soap web services on JAVA, those are running on Linux Server and my distro is deepin

Thanks a lot

Comment: Lots of ways to generate an SSL cert: OpenSSL, Java KeyTool, Windows Certmgr. If you need one that's publicly accepted, you can buy one from the large agencies like verisign, godaddy, etc.

Comment: Could you please share your webserver details and on which OS are you running on.

Comment: My server is on linux, my os of course is deepin
PD: I dont want to buy the ssl, so let's encrypt is the only one who has this service for free